# Swift doubly strange when negative

Tags: swift, function, swift3, xcode8

**Xcode 8.2.1, Swift 3.**

```
import UIKit

extension Double {
    /// Linear interpolation.
    /// Converts a number in one range to its equivalent in another range.
    func interpolate(from: ClosedRange<Int>, to: ClosedRange<Int>) -> Double {
        let oldValue = self
        let offset = Double(to.lowerBound - from.lowerBound)
        let expansion = Double(to.upperBound - to.lowerBound) / Double(from.upperBound - from.lowerBound)

        print("\nvalue", oldValue)
        print("Sign", self.sign)
        print("offset", offset)
        print("expansion", expansion)
        print("oldLowerbound", Double(from.lowerBound))

        let newValue = (oldValue - Double(from.lowerBound)) * expansion + offset
        return newValue
    }
}
print( 1.0.interpolate(from: 0...10, to: 50...70)) // Prints 52.0.  Correct
print(-1.0.interpolate(from: 0...10, to: 50...70)) // Prints -52.0.  Expected 48.0.
print((-1.0).interpolate(from: 0...10, to: 50...70)) // Prints 48. Correct.
```

Unit tests pay for themselves when they reveal unexpected problems in the most (seemingly) trivial code:

(The code above will run in an iOS playground.)

Is there a way to extend`Double`in order to get the second print statement to work as expected (without resorting to brackets as in the third print statement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of evaluation order. Your second expression is evaluated as

```
-(1.0.interpolate(from: 0...10, to: 50...70)) // -52.0
```

i.e. `interpolate()` is called on `1.0`, and the result negated.

You have to set explicit parentheses as in your third expression, so that `interpolate()` is called on `-1.0`:

```
(-1.0).interpolate(from: 0...10, to: 50...70) // 48.0.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Martin.  I was aware that evaluation order was the cause of the problem but was hoping there might be a way around it.  It seems not.

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan: Btw, there is an error in your code, it should be `let offset = Double(to.lowerBound)` . Try `0.0.interpolate(from: -5...5, to: -5...5)` as an example!

Comment: You're right.  The fact that my "from" range always started at zero masked that error.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Martin R is correct, it's a matter of evaluation order, sadly (as far as I know) infix operator (in this case `-`) cannot have precedence specified. The only way I came up with is make custom interpolation operator

```
infix operator ~|
func ~|(lhs: Double, rhs: (from: ClosedRange<Int>, to: ClosedRange<Int>)) -> Double {
  return lhs.interpolate(from: rhs.from, to: rhs.to)
}
```

so the result is:

```
-1.0 ~| (from: 0...10, to: 50...70) // prints 48
```

and to prevent Double extension method interpolate to be called directly it could be file-privately encapsulated in the same file.

Comment: It seems like, no matter what the (coding) problem there is always someone who can solve it! This is an ingenious solution, although it's somewhat less obvious than wrapping the value in brackets.  I wish operators were not limited to vaguely mathematical squiggles but could also be words.